# Confusion about Einstein's field equations

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

There is an issue I'm having regarding the Einstein field equation I would like clarification on... Given that:
$$R_{\mu v} -\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu v}R=kT_{\mu v}$$
Why can't the $g_{\mu v}R$ term be converted to $R_{\mu v}$? turning the field equations into:
$$R_{\mu v} -\frac{1}{2}R_{\mu v}=kT_{\mu v}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}R_{\mu v}=kT_{\mu v}$$

Comment: Because $g_{\mu\nu}R$ is not the same thing as $R_{\mu\nu}$, in general. Why do you think they're the same? If you address this, perhaps we can better clarify your doubt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$R = g^{\mu\nu} R_{\mu\nu}$ does NOT mean $R_{\mu\nu} = R g_{\mu\nu}$.